# Linuxtv linstalation on chromeos

Tags: linux, debian, chrome-os, linux-tv

I need to install this driver to make my DVB-T USB dongle work. I used this tutorial https://rk.edu.pl/pl/obsluga-tunerow-dvb-t-pod-linuksem/

Here is what I did:

```
git clone git://linuxtv.org/media_build.git
cd media_build
```

Then I run command `./build`.  When I do this, I get several errors:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1668 kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Error: could not get list of modules: No such file or directory

Preparing to compile for kernel version 5.4.163

File not found: /lib/modules/5.4.163-17364-gfe3d4f499cf1/build/.config at ./scripts/make_kconfig.pl line 33, <IN> line 4.make[1]: *** [Makefile:367: allyesconfig] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/tabsik12/media_build/v4l'
make: *** [Makefile:26: allyesconfig] Error 2
can't select all drivers at ./build line 531
```

How can I fix this?  I have little knowledge about Linux on Chrome OS.

Comment: Probably not compatible with ARM.

Comment: i have intel processor not arm

Comment: If so then probably not compatible with the ChromeOS security model. Much more plausible than my first comment because that's what the error message suggests.

Comment: maybe is other way to make my Not Only tv Realtek RTL2832  dvbt dongle to work

Comment: Did you read the README about the project no longer being maintained? https://git.linuxtv.org/media_build.git/tree/README

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the Linux kernel provided for ChromeOS is built without loadable module support. See the output below from my ChromeOS linux shell.

```
arul@penguin$ zcat /proc/config.gz |egrep -w "CONFIG_MODULES"
# CONFIG_MODULES is not set
arul@penguin$ 
arul@penguin$ lsmod
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1668 kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Error: could not get list of modules: No such file or directory
arul@penguin$ 
arul@penguin$ ls /lib/modules
ls: cannot access '/lib/modules': No such file or directory
```